# Use Trelliscope with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rendering

I know that this question has been asked before, but so far has not been answered. If there is someone who could point to a working solution (any example is fine) pls share with me. I am regularly checking on the web (since 1 year) but so far notbody has solved the "trelliscope render shiny" problem. 
The code below should work, but in shiny only the title appears, no error message on the plot.
Your help is highly appreciated! Best Alex

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)
devtools::install_github("hafen/trelliscopejs")
library(trelliscopejs)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello trelliscope in Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  fluidPage(

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      trelliscopeOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "400px")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderTrelliscope(
    qplot(year, lifeExp, data = gapminder) +
      xlim(1948, 2011) + ylim(10, 95) + theme_bw() +
      facet_trelliscope(~ country + continent,
                        nrow = 2, ncol = 7, width = 300, as_plotly = TRUE)

    )
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, apparently [you're not alone](https://github.com/hafen/trelliscopejs/issues/37). I guess you'll have to wait until the package maintainer solves this problem

Comment: Hi, finally I found a working solution....

Answer (score 2):

Finally I´ve been able to get a working solution with some limitations though.
I´ve created an app within RStudio: File -> New File -> Shiny Web App. In the app folder it seems that you have to create a "www" directory and set self_contained = TRUE. The below example works on my Mac.

````
library(trelliscopejs)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  trelliscopeOutput(outputId = "plot")
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderTrelliscope({

    ggplot2::mpg %>%
      group_by(manufacturer, class) %>%
      nest() %>%
      mutate(
        panel = map_plot(data, ~
                           ggplot(data = ., aes(x = cty, y = hwy)) +
                           geom_point(color = I("red")) +
                           theme_bw())) %>%
      trelliscope(name = "output", self_contained = TRUE)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: Tried to replicate it but received following error: attempt to use zero-length variable name